# Automated Lottery Logic : How to choose winners for 3 possible prizes in known quantities

Tags: logic

So I have been tasked with designing the methodology for an automated lottery. I'm having trouble conceptualizing it and I'm hoping you fine folks can point me in the right direction.

There are 3 possible prizes (A, B, C) of known quantities available (N[A], N[B], N[C]).  We know the duration the contest will run, but we do not know how many people will participate in the lottery. This contest logic will be used several times and the prize quantities and duration of the contest may change. Winners should be distributed at random-ish intervals throughout the duration of the contest.

Participants visit a webpage and they are shown if they have won a prize or not and, if so, which prize they have won.  How do we choose which participants are winners and which prize the winner has won ?

Comment: Based on what you've given here, the answer would be "any way you like." More specific requirements would be needed to settle on a suitable methodology. Details would include (e.g.) the rules -- can one contestant win more than one prize? How should contestants identify themselves -- e.g. what if two contestants are named "John Smith?" What events define the "duration" of the contest, given that prizes can apparently be awarded while entries are still being submitted (an approach that btw doesn't seem to make much sense)? Getting answers to these questions should make it clear how to proceed.

Comment: These details are omitted because they are not relevant.  The mechanism for excluding repeat participants is outside of the scope.  We can assume that each person entering the lottery is eligible to play. People have other identifying data than name, so we will use email address. This is still irrelevant since their name has no bearing on their chances to win. The duration of the lottery makes sense if you think of it as multiple lotteries, which should be clear from my description. See Oerkelen's answer, that's really the type of thing I was looking for.

Comment: I understand, I was just trying to convey the real problem:  the vagueness of the assignment as described.  In this situation there is no "right" approach and quite possibily the person giving the assignment is testing your personal insight, experience, and creativity.  So it would be better to rely on your own resources for the answer than to tap someone else's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no idea how many people will participate, and at what time they will do so, I would suggest you do not allocate prizes to contestants but to moments in time.

Then, whenever such a moment in time occurs, give the prize to the first participant to visit/participate/answer/whatever.

To distribute the prizes over the allotted time, you can start by distributing each prize evenly over the total time (depending on N[x]).

Then offset each timestamp with a random timespan between -T and T, where T is half the time between the prize moments.

If you want to avoid times falling in the night time (meaning in the morning people have a higher chance of winning by logging in early), simply adjust your formula's to skip the "night hours" as possible outcomes.

Comment: I had considered an interval, but I had some concerns about randomness, or people learning the interval and participating at time predetermined to give the next prize. This solution avoids that nicely and you even considered off-peak participants which had not occurred to me. I'll give some time for more answers and then almost certainly select your answer. Thanks!